# Not getting headers in the response

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2

I am setting this header in WEB API but getting in response on client

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Headers.Add("x-total-records", documentData.TotalItemsCount.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

Why its not coming in response

Comment: are you sure that documentData.TotalItemsCount.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) returns something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do this in your mvc function

```
Request.Properties.Add("x-total-records", documentData.TotalItemsCount.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

And create a filter like this

```
public class CustomHeaderFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
    {
        if (actionExecutedContext.Request.Properties.Any(p => p.Key == "x-total-records"))
        {
            actionExecutedContext.Response.Content.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "x-total-records");
            actionExecutedContext.Response.Content.Headers.Add("x-total-records", actionExecutedContext.Request.Properties["x-total-records"].ToString());
        }


    }
}
```

Hopfuly this will solve your issue